# IPP QBO v3 UK - trouble adding invoice

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

The following code was working a few weeks ago but now I get an error message. Any ideas? Note this is QuickBooks Online United Kingdom edition.

I'm adding additional information here so that I can save the form. Without adding this additional information I am unable to post this question.

```
<outgoing><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Invoice xmlns:ns2="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbo" xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
    <CustomerId>1</CustomerId>
    <CustomerRef>1</CustomerRef>
    <SalesTermRef>3</SalesTermRef>
    <DocNumber>101</DocNumber>
    <CustomerMemo>Thank you for your order!</CustomerMemo>
    <TxnDate>2014-03-05</TxnDate>
    <PrivateNote>Special Handling</PrivateNote>
    <BillEmail>
      <Address>janice@johnson.com</Address>
    </BillEmail>
    <PrintStatus>NotSet</PrintStatus>
    <EmailStatus>NeedToSend</EmailStatus>
    <ApplyTaxAfterDiscount></ApplyTaxAfterDiscount>
    <ShipDate>2014-03-05</ShipDate>
    <TrackingNum>1Z9999W99999999999</TrackingNum>
    <BillAddr>
      <Line1>110 Main Street</Line1>
      <Line2>Suite 2000</Line2>
      <Line3></Line3>
      <Line4></Line4>
      <City>Dallas</City>
      <CountrySubDivisionCode>TX</CountrySubDivisionCode>
      <PostalCode>99875</PostalCode>
      <Country></Country>
    </BillAddr>
    <ShipAddr>
      <Line1>110 Main Street</Line1>
      <Line2>Suite 2000</Line2>
      <Line3></Line3>
      <Line4></Line4>
      <City>Dallas</City>
      <CountrySubDivisionCode>TX</CountrySubDivisionCode>
      <PostalCode>99875</PostalCode>
      <Country></Country>
    </ShipAddr>
    <Line>
      <Description>Blue MP3 Player</Description>
      <Amount>110.00</Amount>
      <DetailType>SalesItemLineDetail</DetailType>
      <SalesItemLineDetail>
        <ItemRef>3</ItemRef>
        <Qty>2</Qty>
        <UnitPrice>55</UnitPrice>
        <TaxCodeRef>3</TaxCodeRef>
      </SalesItemLineDetail>
    </Line>
    <Line>
      <Description></Description>
      <Amount></Amount>
      <DetailType>DiscountLineDetail</DetailType>
      <DiscountLineDetail>
        <PercentBased>true</PercentBased>
        <DiscountPercent>0.0200</DiscountPercent>
      </DiscountLineDetail>
    </Line>
    <Line>
      <Description></Description>
      <Amount>12.00</Amount>
      <DetailType>SalesItemLineDetail</DetailType>
      <SalesItemLineDetail>
        <ItemRef>SHIPPING_ITEM_ID</ItemRef>
        <Qty></Qty>
        <UnitPrice></UnitPrice>
        <TaxCodeRef>3</TaxCodeRef>
      </SalesItemLineDetail>
    </Line>
  </Invoice>
</outgoing>
<returns><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2014-04-17T11:42:01.411-07:00">
    <Fault type="ValidationFault">
      <Error code="6440" element="">
        <Message>Transaction Detail Information Required</Message>
        <Detail>You must select a product/service or an account for each split line with either an amount or a billable customer.</Detail>
      </Error>
    </Fault>
  </IntuitResponse>
</returns>
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. In QBO preferences I had to enable shipping.